# JOGL library - universality

Tags: java, jogl

I want to use JOGL ibrary and I want to use it on linux and windows...
Will project compiled on linux run on windows?
Do I have to change included libraries if I want to compile it for windows?

Regards,
Peter.

Comment: I think you'll just have to link to the corresponding native libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked under GNU Linux (currently Mageia Linux 4) with JOGL since 2006 and I can confirm that my first person shooter works as expected on any operating system supporting the Java Runtime Environment including GNU Linux, Mac OS X, OpenIndiana, Microsoft Windows, ... I compile and build it under GNU Linux. I even build my own self-contained native application bundles under GNU Linux with [JNDT](https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2014/11/22/ardor3d-est-mort-vive-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation-ardor3d-is-dead-long-life-to-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation/#jndt) and several end users confirmed that they work very well. In other words, I don't need to be under Mac or Windows even to create "native" Java applications.

Vodlez is right even though I wouldn't use the term "link". JOGL 2 provides some JARs containing the native libraries, I advise you to put them all (including those NOT for your own operating system) into your project or to use a build tool (Ant, Maven, Gradle, ...) that does it for you so that other developers can run your project but anyway, when you compile, you don't need those JARs. You can set the Java library path too and then you have to take care of pointing out to the directory containing the appropriate native libraries.